# Batch: Setting one variable from other variables

Tags: batch-file

What I'm trying to do should be simple for batch veterans. I have a list of Environment Variables:

CORE1
CORE2
CORE3, etc

I'm trying to set them to a new variable called HOSTS. Each of the variable should be separated by spaces.So HOSTS = "CORE1 CORE2 CORE3"

```
for /L %%x in (1,1,20) do (
    IF "!CORE%x!"=="" (
        goto continue
    )
    IF NOT "!CORE%x!"=="" ( 
        set HOSTS = "%HOSTS% !CORE%x!"
    )
) 
:continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to concatenate the contents of several variables `CORE1` to `CORE20` - if set - into a variable `HOSTS`, with spaces separating the individual values. You can do it like this (I've added some example values to make for a runnable example):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET CORE1=1
SET CORE3=3
SET CORE4=4
SET CORE6=6
SET CORE8=8
SET CORE12=12
SET CORE17=17

for /L %%x in (1,1,20) do (
    IF "!HOSTS!"=="" ( 
        :: avoid leading space on first value
        SET HOSTS=!CORE%%x!
    ) ELSE (
        IF NOT "!CORE%%x!"=="" ( 
            SET HOSTS=!HOSTS! !CORE%%x!
        )
    )
)

ECHO %HOSTS%
```

This script will output:

```
1 3 4 6 8 12 17
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for you?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inc=0
:heck
set /a "inc+=1"
if defined CORE%inc% (
    set "HOSTS=%HOSTS% !CORE%inc%!
    goto heck
)
rem remove leading space from %HOSTS%
set HOSTS=%HOSTS:~1%
```

Here's a more complete test script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set CORE1=foo
set CORE2=bar
set CORE3=baz
set CORE4=qux
set CORE5=quux
set CORE6=corge
set CORE7=grault
set CORE8=garply
set CORE9=waldo
set CORE10=fred
set CORE11=plugh
set CORE12=xyzzy
set CORE13=thud

set inc=0
:heck
set /a "inc+=1"
if defined CORE%inc% (
    set "HOSTS=%HOSTS% !CORE%inc%!
    goto heck
)
rem remove leading space from %HOSTS%
set HOSTS=%HOSTS:~1%

echo %HOSTS%
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>test
foo bar baz qux quux corge grault garply waldo fred plugh xyzzy thud
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: set 'COREn' to a value for testing
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,10) DO SET core%%i=str%%i
::
(SET hosts=)
FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%i IN ('set core') DO CALL :addval %%i
ECHO hosts=%hosts%
GOTO :eof

:addval
IF DEFINED hosts (SET hosts=%hosts% %1) ELSE (SET hosts=%1)
GOTO :EOF
```

are you concerned about the precise sequence of elements? This will accumulate all values of vars CORE* in alphabetical order of the envvar name

Answer (score 0):

```
set HOSTS=%CORE1%
for /L %%x in (2,1,20) do (
   if defined CORE%%x (
      set "HOSTS=!HOSTS! !CORE%%x!"
   )
)
```

Antonio